# Jquery Javascript Replace String

Tags: jquery, replace, wysiwyg

The wysiwyg editor I'm using uses this to replace the `<strong>` with a span style.  I modified to add a code block.

```
v=v.replace(/<strong>(.*)<\/strong>/gi,'<span style="font-weight: bold;">$1</span>');
```

This works fine until I highlight code with

```
v=v.replace(/<pre>(.*)<\/pre>/gi,'<div id="precode"> $1 </div>');
```

I have been looking and can't fine any info on replace. Can someone explain

Can someone explain this part of the code? I'm sure it will help others as well

```
.replace(/<strong>(.*)<\/strong>/gi,'
```

> Is there something in this causing the it to add the new style to each
>   line

```
if(id=='style'){
                var sel=document.createElement('select'),
                styles=obj.styles||[['Style',''],['Paragraph','<p>'],['Header 1','<h1>'],['Header 2','<h2>'],['Header 3','<h3>'],['Header 4','<h4>'],['Header 5','<h5>'],['Header 6','<h6>'],['CodeBlock','<pre>']],
                sl=styles.length, x=0;
                sel.className='testyle'; sel.onchange=new Function(this.n+'.ddaction(this,"formatblock")');
                for(x;x<sl;x++){
                    var style=styles[x];
                    sel.options[x]=new Option(style[0],style[1])
                }
```

Comment: replace is a string method which replaces wanted of the string with another. This wanted replacement could be regular expression too. In your case it means that it will find all `<strong>` tags and replace them with `<span>` tags (its a [regular expression](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp))

Comment: also... [read this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass the string to find in /.../gi it looks for all the occurences of that string in the origincal string and replaces it by the string we pass as second parameter. It does not modify the original string so you have to assign its output to some variable in order to use it. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: If I wrap  this   < pre> blah blaeeh </ pre>  everything works fine but if I wrap this  < pre> blah <br> blaeeh </ pre>  It wraps them both like div id="precode">blah < /div> div id="precode">blaeeh< /div>